# Mustache templates: how to refer to external file in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mustache

The following code(*) works, but I would like instead of using:

```
$(this.el).html(Mustache.render("<h2>{{title}}</h2>", view));
```

I would like to do:

```
$(this.el).html(Mustache.render("somePath/myFile.html", view));
```

How can I do it?

(*)

```
render: function () 
{
    var view = {
        response: this.model.title
    };
    $(this.el).html(Mustache.render("<h2>{{{title}}}</h2>", view)); // it works
    $(this.el).html(Mustache.render("myFile.html", view)); // it does not work
},
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do :

```
$.get("myFile.html", function(html) { $(this.el).html(Mustache.render(html, view)) });
```

`$.get` is a shorthand AJAX request for the file which then uses the contents of the file (`html`) as the HTML for Mustache to render.

Comment: I think is an elegant trick to use external files as templates, that's all :)